# How can I rank a list of students and display their names in php

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql table structure looks like this:

```
subject ca  quiz exam exam_cumulative positionineachcourse matric_no   name

Maths   10   20   34      64                                HT/001    John
Econs   14   14   40      68                                HT/002    Mark
History 20   30   60     110                                HT/003    Grace 
Chem    15   15   50      80                                HT/004    Alice
Bio     12   13   60      85                                HT/005    Larry
```

How can get the position of each student in each course and then get also their overall positions like 1ST, SND, 3RD, 4TH and 5TH?

Comment: My eyes hurt...

Comment: It all depends. If each ca, quiz, exam has different percentage then you will haev to do a little more but if they are all the same then you just sum them and sort by the sum DESC

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: "SELECT id, name, score, FIND_IN_SET(rank, (    
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rank ORDER BY score DESC ) 
FROM scores )) AS position FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC"

Comment: Thanks WheatBeak. I ranked the students using:  "SELECT  name, exam_cummulative, FIND_IN_SET(matric_no, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT matric_no ORDER BY exam_cummulative DESC ) 
FROM `{$tablename}` )) AS rank FROM `{$tablename} ORDER BY exam_cummulative DESC".  Output: Grace 110, Larry 85, Alice 80, Mark 68, John 64. Now my major problem:  How do I echo POSITION of each student: eg. Grace 1ST, Larry 2ND, Alice 3RD, Mark 4TH, John 5TH. Am I supposed to create another table for position? If yes, how do I link Grace who has the highest score to the 1ST position, Larry  to 2ND position, etc.